# Magento 1.9 Catch product options event

Tags: php, magento

I have a store with product color options.
I use magento 1.9.

How can I catch Color Change event from php source?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that handles changes in configurable product options is js/varien/configurable.js

Take a look in there, see if you can figure it out. If not, come back and post some actual code for us to look at.